# controller and template of child state is not getting invoked. Transitioned from sibling of child's parent state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular js and ui router. i am planning to design a angular js ui routed app. I have a two states, state A and State B. State B has child state.
on the landing page of the app (which is a query panel) state A is invoked correctly. Interaction with landing page should present the result which is routed as State B's child state.

app.js

```
$stateProvider
  .state('A', {
    url: '/queryPanel',
    templateUrl: 'queryParameterView.html'
  })
  .state('B', {
    url: '/resultPanel',
  })
  .state('B.child', {
    url: '/overView',
    templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
    }
  });
```

so basically I want to transition from state A to State B's child states (i.e B.child)

```
<a ui-sref="B.child" class="btn btn-primary">show xyz</a>
```

This is how I am trying to invoke the child state.

However it isn't working. when I hit the button `show xyz` the url changes from
`localhost:1234/queryPanel` to `localhost:1234/resultPanel/overView` but the controller and template doesn't get invoked / loaded.

How should I go about solving this problem?. I am following this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a child states, you must make sure that in the parent state's view, it has a `ui-view` directive so that the child states can resides on it.

One immediate problem I can see with your `$state` configuration is that at your `B` state, you do not have a `template` or `templateUrl` property. What you should do is something like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('A', {
    url: '/queryPanel',
    templateUrl: 'queryParameterView.html'
  })
  .state('B', {
    url: '/resultPanel',
    template:'<div ui-view></div>' // or you can use templateUrl
  })
  .state('B.child', {
    url: '/overView',
    templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
    }
  });
```

Edit: Added [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yrIp3hWuEQTL8Ee2OOrC?p=preview)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I tried this solution, but it didn't work. My URL also doesn't change (which was changing earlier to child state URL).

Comment: @AjinkyaKale You really need to debug it and find out what's wrong. I added a working plnkr for you, just in case you need a reference

Comment: sure thank you so much for your help! plnkr is very good reference.